# Correct way to " pull " xml into API?

Tags: php, xml, api

What would be the correct way to pull the xml, into the API?

Example of straight xml in the api code; ( which is what we dont want, we need it to pull the xml from a file )

```
BigCommerce_Api::useXml();

$xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <brand>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <search_keywords>computers laptops</search_keywords>
    </brand>";

$result = BigCommerce_Api::createBrand($xml);
```

My dodgy attempt at bringing in the xml via fopen;

```
<?
require_once 'BigCommerce/Api.php';

BigCommerce_Api::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://apiurl',
'username'  => 'admin',
'api_key'   => 'apitoken'
));

$filename = "xmlfile.xml";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$XPost = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

BigCommerce_Api::useXml();

$xml = $XPost;

$result = BigCommerce_Api::createProduct($xml); 

?>
```

If anyone could let us know how to bring the xml into the useXML var appropriately, feel free to share :)

( some of the formatting of the code is paying up after quotes applied )

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a tip: Don't use shorttags (e.g., use `<?php` instead of `<?`). They're controversial and there's some evidence they'll be deprecated (if they're not already). This question, FWIW, is a toss-up between `Too Localized` or `Not a Real Question`.

Comment: You may want to look into [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why you make your life that complicated:

```
BigCommerce_Api::useXml();

$xml = file_get_contents('xmlfile.xml');

$result = BigCommerce_Api::createBrand($xml);
```

See [`file_get_contents`](http://de.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff: there is no problem with the de. subdomain in front of php.net. It is just a mirror, you see the same as on php.net only faster.

Comment: It depends where you live. It would make it slower if you are on the other side of the world. (I don't put links to http://nz.php.net just because I am in New Zealand). Also, when using the Beta PHP.net, the `This is a work-in-progress experimental design` message appears.

Comment: Unless your cookie is not set, you will still see a redirect to your local mirror. It's just that you will see it faster because at specific times of day php.net is slow with that redirect.

Comment: Doesn't redirect me. I have the cookie set.

Comment: Must it with cookies? Normally this is not an issue, php.net for example doesn't always redirect, too and it is not so that it is the best mirror for me.

Comment: Well, it might not be with cookies (I am using Alpha though), but *any* PHP.net site doesn't redirect for me. (People post links to `us3.`, `es.`, `de.`, etc.)